# Parse a complex JavaScript expression to rewrite it in another format

Tags: javascript, c#, json, parsing

I think I'm going to get laughed at for asking this, but oh well.

I am trying to refactor a legacy app where there is validation and and conditional rendering logic in JavaScript expressions stored in a data column in the database.  The expressions are boolean in nature, but some are rather complex.  An example would be like:

```
([!Var6!] == '4' || [!Var6!] == '5' || [!Var6!] == '6') && ([!Var1!] == '2' || [!Var2!] >= 65 || [!Var3!] == '5' || [!Var4!] == '6')
```

...where the `[!...!]` notation signifies a variable stored in JavaScript.

I need to translate this in my C# application to a more orderly format in structured JSON to feed another application, something that would resemble the notation below.  The complexity of the expressions makes this prohibitive to roll my own parser... so I'm hoping there is a means to do so that someone else has already written, or there is a neat trick I don't know in Visual Studio or the .NET framework to do the parsing of this mess.

```
{
    "condition": { // expression object
        "expressions": [
            { //expression object representing ([!Var6!] == '4' || [!Var6!] == '5' || [!Var6!] == '6')
                "expressions": [
                    { //expression object representing [!Var6!] == '4'
                        "left_operand": {
                            "type": "variable",
                            "value": "Var6"
                        },
                        "operator": "eq",
                        "right_operand": {
                            "type": "numeric",
                            "value": 4
                        }
                    },
                    { //expression object representing [!Var6!] == '5'
                        "left_operand": {
                            "type": "variable",
                            "value": "Var6"
                        },
                        "operator": "eq",
                        "right_operand": {
                            "type": "numeric",
                            "value": 5
                        }
                    },
                    { //expression object representing [!Var6!] == '6'
                        "left_operand": {
                            "type": "variable",
                            "value": "Var6"
                        },
                        "operator": "eq",
                        "right_operand": {
                            "type": "numeric",
                            "value": 6
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "logical_operation": "or"
            },
            { //expression object representing ([!Var1!] == '2' || [!Var2!] >= 65 || [!Var3!] == '5' || [!Var4!] == '6')
                "expressions": [
                    { //expression representing [!Var1!] == '2'
                        "left_operand": {
                            "type": "variable",
                            "value": "Var1"
                        },
                        "operator": "eq",
                        "right_operand": {
                            "type": "numeric",
                            "value": 2
                        }
                    },
                    { //expression representing [!Var2!] >= 65
                        "left_operand": {
                            "type": "variable",
                            "value": "Var2"
                        },
                        "operator": "gte",
                        "right_operand": {
                            "type": "numeric",
                            "value": 65
                        }
                    },
                    { //expression representing [!Var3!] == '5'
                        "left_operand": {
                            "type": "variable",
                            "value": "Var3"
                        },
                        "operator": "eq",
                        "right_operand": {
                            "type": "numeric",
                            "value": 5
                        }
                    },
                    { //expression representing [!Var4!] == '6'
                        "left_operand": {
                            "type": "variable",
                            "value": "Var4"
                        },
                        "operator": "eq",
                        "right_operand": {
                            "type": "numeric",
                            "value": 6
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "logical_operation": "or"
            }
        ],
        "logical_operation": "and"
    }
```

Comment: I guess you're screwed :( At least for the parsing part, json could easily be fixed once you have it in c# code but... Glad I don't have that work in front of me. A line of thought though, in what way would it benefit the end-user to go from one complex notion to another complex notion? Why not just send the blob and let them deal with it? I mean they would have to 'write spec. custom code' anyways so just send them the original chunk?

Comment: @DanielMesSer As you might imagine, it's... complicated.  There were competing standards for web services providers... Leadership liked the clients of the one system, and the supported functionality of the services in the other.  So now I have to make the services provide what the clients are expecting.  Yay me...

Comment: Does a javascript solution interest you at all?

Comment: I think there is no other way than writing your own parser. You can take a look at [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) class and all infrastructure build around it, as an example of how such things can be solved.

Comment: So you want to parse the Javascript expressions in all of their complexity; OK, you probably need a JavaScript parser.  You want to transform this JSON format, right?  Do you have to do that translation in realtime, or can you do it offline during development?  How much (JavaScript) code is going to need to be translated? (If offline translation is OK, you can likely use a program transformation system to do this.  If that's what you want, I can outline an answer).

Comment: @IraBaxter thanks, but this does need to be real-time.

Comment: Would it be useful to use the output of a JavaScript-to-.NET compiler? That's essentially what Jurassic is (jurassic.codeplex.com). You could pick apart its output - although it is all in memory since Jurassic is meant to execute the code immediately. Jurassic also has to do some of the expression work you mention above. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first and maybe main problem is to transform the javascript expressions into an AST that can then be further processed.

Use one of the open source parsers to get an AST.

I would recommend the typescript compiler as it has a very clean codebase (valid javascript is always valid typescript). Uglify is also very well suited and its author maintains very good information about processing the AST.

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/src/compiler
- http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/